# If $g_0$ is any element of a group $G$, show that as $g$ ranges over $G$ so does $gg_0$.

Tags: group-theory

> If $g_0$ is any element of a group $G$, show that as $g$ ranges over $G$ so does $gg_0$

Not sure how to show this. Been trying to find something on the web that explains how to do it but nothing.

Comment: You're asked to show that every element of $G$ can be written in the form $gg_0$ (for the fixed element $g_0$ and a suitable element $g$).

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you need to prove is $\{gg_0\vert g\in G\}=G$.

Let's define $f:g\longrightarrow gg_0$. What you are asked to do is to prove that $f$ is bijective (actually it suffices to say that it's surjective).

Anyway it's pretty straightforward to prove that $f':g\longrightarrow gg_0^{-1}$ is actually $f^{-1}$ so $f$ is bijective. Hence $\{gg_0\vert g\in G\}=f(G)=G$

Comment: If you delete the second paragraph this is good but $f$ is definitely not a group morphism (unless $g_0=1_G$) and $G$ is not assumed to be finite so injective is not equivalent to surjective.

Comment: @both, I stand corrected, sorry for the mistakes I corrected it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you have to verify that given $g,h\in G$ with $g\not=h$, then $gg_0\not=h g_0$. But this is actually true because, if not, since $G$ is a group, $$gg_0=h g_0 \implies g=h.$$ So $\{gg_0:g\in G\}$ has as many elements as $G$.

Comment: This only works if $G$ is finite, which doesn't appear to be in the hypotheses.

Comment: In which line did I use the hypotheses of $G$ be finite?

Comment: I can give easy examples of injective functions of an infinite set into itself that are not surjective. I'm sure you can, too.

Comment: Each $gg_0$ is image of $g$ so...

Comment: So what? The map $x\mapsto 2x$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ shows that there are as many even numbers as natural numbers. Does it show every natural number is even?

Comment: Under which operation is $\mathbb{N}$ a group?

Comment: I *KNOW* the map $g\mapsto gg_0$ is bijective! But yours is *NOT* a proof.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. Do we have to prove that $g_0G=G$ or that both sets have the same cardinality?

Comment: @Jccalab, both are equivalent statements since $g_0G\subseteq G$.

Comment: @Jccalab The request is to prove that $Gg_0=G$. The map $x\mapsto xg_0$ *is* injective, but this doesn't prove it is surjective. This *particular* map *is* surjective, but not simply for the reason it is injective, because there exist injective maps from an infinite set into itself that are not surjective. Of course, noting that *this* map has an inverse suffices to end the proof.